# How to extend mutual modifiers with Stylus?

Tags: css, stylus

I have a header with some modifiers:

```
.header {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.header--main {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}
.header--type-error {
  color: red;
}
.header--main.header--type-error {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

More stylish:

```
.header {
  font-weight: bold;
  &--main {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  }
  &--type-error {
    color: red;
  }
  &--main&--type-error {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
}
```

If I want to extend Error__header with the header and his mods, I can do it like this

```
.Error__header {
  @extend .header;
  @extend .header--main;
  @extend .header--type-error;
  @extend .header--main.header--type-error;
}
```

Is there a solution for getting effect of `@extend .header--main.header--type-error` without writing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For obvious reasons you can't have some effect without doing anything for it :)

However, in your case, you could want to use [placeholder selector](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/extend.html#extending-placeholder-selectors) alongside with [root reference](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/selectors.html#root-reference):

```
.header,
$foo {
  font-weight: bold;
  &--main,
  /$foo {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  }
  &--type-error,
  /$foo {
    color: red;
  }
  &--main&--type-error,
  /$foo {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
}

.Error__header {
  @extend $foo;
}
```

would be equal to the code you wrote. And if you'd wanted not to have all the selectors like `.Error__header--main.Error__header--type-error` generated and only the `.Error__header` added to each of those, you can do this:

```
.header {
  &,
  /$foo {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  &--main,
  /$foo {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  }
  &--type-error,
  /$foo {
    color: red;
  }
  &--main&--type-error,
  /$foo {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
}

.Error__header {
  @extend $foo;
}
```

and this would compile to

```
.header,
.Error__header {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.header--main,
.Error__header {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}
.header--type-error,
.Error__header {
  color: #f00;
}
.header--main.header--type-error,
.Error__header {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```